# Php : Possible to copy fields?

Tags: php

So basically I am having the user fill out a form, at the end, I ask for billing information (Address, city, state, zip, etc),  Then I again ask for shipping information (Same).  Inbetween them, ive added a check box that asks if the shipping information is the same as the billing information, if they check the box, I want to copy the information into the correct fields for them.   I know that they is accomplished easily in javascript, but that is not what our class is in. I tried searching the web for a while now and came up with no results, so my question is, is it possible to do this using only php and html? Or do I have to use javascript to do so?

Comment: Is all this happening on the same page? If so, then answer is No, you can not do it in PHP. Whats wrong involving javascript to do the job?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is. (If it's different pages). Just change where you output the form and check if the POST value exists.

Comment: PHP is server-based. Javascript executes entirely within the browser. You can accomplish a field copy with a server roundtrip, but it's not a good design - a server roundtrip is not necessary. Javascript is how they would normally do it.

Comment: PHP is server side, JS is client side. PHP can't mess with the client page (copying values, modifying them etc...) unless they're sent to the server through a form submit.

Comment: as above - use Javascript, this is client functionality you are looking to implement, not server side

Comment: Thank your for all the answers/comments.  Theres nothing wrong with doing in with javascript, but the class is PHP-programming so if figured, it was be better to use php if possible.  My final decision is to just say screw it and use javascript though, easier, and I already know how to do it. But Thanks everyone!